# LightGBM cross validation algorithm question - boosting rounds

Tags: lightgbm

If I understand correctly, the cv() method evaluates a model for each fold in parallel, stopping at the same number of iterations for each model.

What is the reason for this default behaviour? My intuition would be to pass the validation sets and a common value for early stopping rounds and allow the number of iterations to vary until each model is sufficiently complex.

Any thoughts appreciated :)